# I have added a HTTP Redirect in IIS7 and removed it. Still it is in use. How to delete it permanently?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have unchecked the Redirect check box in HTTP REDIRECT in IIS7. But still the Rule is working. How to remove it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restart IIS by opening cmd window and executing following command:

```
iisreset
```

or restart World Wide Web Publishing Service from computer services.

Comment: Gregor Primar ya i did that too and Its working after clearing the cache in chrome.